# Getting error importing into phpMyAdmin a database exported from phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, drupal, import, phpmyadmin, export

I'm trying to deploy my Drupal 7 site from my local dev server to an online host.

I export my database using the export function in phpMyAdmin and then import the file on the host end also using phpMyAdmin. PhpMyAdmin versions are the same on both ends, and I have tried both the quick export and many settings, matching settings on the import, and I get the same #1064 syntax error every time. However I don't see any issues with the SQL, it looks fine to me. I have also taken the exported SQL and pasted it into phpMyAdmin as a SQL statement and get the exact same error when I run it.

Here's the error:

```
Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

A closing bracket was expected. (near ")" at position 88)
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `actions` ( `aid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT )

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 3
```

Here's the top of the SQL file where the error is triggered:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `actions` (
  `aid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'COMMENT
);

INSERT INTO `actions` (`aid`, `type`, `callback`, `parameters`, `label`) VALUES
('comment_publish_action', 'comment', 'comment_publish_action', '', 'Publish comment'),
('comment_save_action', 'comment', 'comment_save_action', '', 'Save comment'),
('comment_unpublish_action', 'comment', 'comment_unpublish_action', '', 'Unpublish comment'),
('node_make_sticky_action', 'node', 'node_make_sticky_action', '', 'Make content sticky'),
('node_make_unsticky_action', 'node', 'node_make_unsticky_action', '', 'Make content unsticky'),
('node_promote_action', 'node', 'node_promote_action', '', 'Promote content to front page'),
('node_publish_action', 'node', 'node_publish_action', '', 'Publish content'),
('node_save_action', 'node', 'node_save_action', '', 'Save content'),
('node_unpromote_action', 'node', 'node_unpromote_action', '', 'Remove content from front page'),
('node_unpublish_action', 'node', 'node_unpublish_action', '', 'Unpublish content'),
('pathauto_node_update_action', 'node', 'pathauto_node_update_action', '', 'Update node alias'),
('pathauto_taxonomy_term_update_action', 'taxonomy_term', 'pathauto_taxonomy_term_update_action', '', 'Update taxonomy term alias'),
('pathauto_user_update_action', 'user', 'pathauto_user_update_action', '', 'Update user alias'),
('system_block_ip_action', 'user', 'system_block_ip_action', '', 'Ban IP address of current user'),
('user_block_user_action', 'user', 'user_block_user_action', '', 'Block current user');
```

Anyone else encountered this before? Any suggestions for a remedy? This should work (I've done this before) and I don't want to back the site out for a generic new Drupal install just to get Backup & Migrate module installed to do this transfer of data.

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? There was a version where the parser didn't extract COMMENT data correctly and it appears as if you're using that version (notice the `DEFAULT '0'COMMENT` portion, in particular). Probably the easiest solution is to upgrade your phpMyAdmin installations on both sides to the latest version compatible with your MySQL and PHP versions.